# Replace NA with an empty string

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a long google-sheet formula, how can I wrap it with a condition so N/A only would be replaced with an empty string?

If know `=IFNA(a, "",a)` but I don't want to repeat the long formula (`a`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[IFNA(value, value_if_na)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9365944) expects 2 parameters:**

- `value`: The value to check if it is a #N/A error.
- `value_if_na`: The value to return if the first argument is an #N/A error.

Your formula should be this: `=IFNA(a, "")`

Comment: and if not "na" than the value remains?